# Google Analytics- conversion path for product type or SKU

Tags: api, google-analytics

Is it possible to get attribution reports through the multi-channel API by product type or SKU? We are interested in learning more about attribution for different product types... not just the site overall. Ideally, we'd like it by transaction ID, but someone posted that this was not an option, likely for privacy reason as it could be personally identifiable?

Comment: Is what your are looking for in the [MCF API Dimensions and Metrics reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/interactions#mcf:transactionId)?